# Spring + Hibernate : Unknown entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to get an annotation based hibernate configuration working.

applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- ============================= -->
<!-- DATASOURCE                    -->
<!-- ============================= -->
<bean name="logDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${logs.ds.jndi.name}"/>
</bean>

<!-- ============================= -->
<!-- SESSION FACTORY               -->
<!-- ============================= -->
<bean id="logSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.logs.persistence.entity"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="logDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- dialect -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${logs.ds.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>

            <!-- schema -->
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${logs.ds.default_schema}</prop>

            <!-- logging debug information -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${logs.ds.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${logs.ds.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${logs.ds.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${logs.ds.debug}</prop>

            <prop key="configurationClass">org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="logTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="logSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

LogsConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.logs.persistence.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "logs_configuration")
public class LogsConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

The problem is, when I try to save a `LogsConfiguration` with my DAO, I get this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.example.logs.persistence.entity.LogsConfiguration
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1533)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:104)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
at com.example.logs.persistence.dao.impl.AbstractDaoImpl.create(AbstractDaoImpl.java:125)
```

Where did I go wrong ? Everything seems ok to me (I am using the `javax.persistence` annotations)

Comment: Do you use Hibernate 5?

Comment: @v.ladynev yes I'm using Hibernate `5.1.0.Final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
My application is a filter and the problem was that I had two session factories.

My DAO was autowiring the wrong one.
To fix that, I added a `@Qualifier` to get the good one.

So I replaced that

```
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

with that

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("logSessionFactory")
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

Your entry would be modified as below:

```
<bean id="logSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.logs.persistence.entity"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="logDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      ...
    </property>
</bean>
```